# use of ntp service

Tags: android, ntp

I'm developing an app that needs to control real time in any location on the Earth and do something when time comes. At the same time not to rely on system time because user can easily change it.
Does anybody have an experience of implementing "sntp/ntp" service on android device or is there any other solution to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Any location on the earth??  Think about what you're saying here, then get a satcom phone.

Comment: @devin Think about how it can be done without satcom phone. GPS position you can get pretty everywhere. If you're able to send coordinates to a service that can find out your time zone by coordinates and send back local time for that zone you are done. I did it using geonames service. :-P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the SNTP client code at:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java

Comment: Any tip which host I can use? Tried with "pool.ntp.org" and  "0.pool.ntp.org", get "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" when try to get host by name.

Comment: From the Honeycomb release forward, you cannot do a network operation in the main thread. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Yeah, right, already had that issue before and forgot. Works perfect now. Thanks.

Comment: That is the SNTP client from the Android source; [here is](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/SntpClient.java/) a more up-to-date version.