# Android - Network Date/Time

Tags: android, date, time, gps, location

I'm in the process of writing an app for Android. I need to allow my users to capture their current location & log the date/time that this happened. The catch is that the date/time cannot be something that the user can change by adjusting the date/time on their device.

Can you point me in the right direction for obtaining the Cellular Network date/time when using location services for towers, and also how to obtain the GPS date/time.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you logging information server-side?  If so, just use the server date/time.

Comment: We are doing this, but the requirement is actually from the government. Their requirement is to use the "GPS Signal Date/Time" or "Cellular Network Date/Time" (depending on how location was retrieved). We are having a similar issue w/ our iPhone app... but I'm not the dev for that :)

Comment: I'd use a GPS hooked up to the server for this.  It would be harder to tamper with, provided you aren't doing delayed uploads.

Comment: But do you know if there is a way to retrieve the cellular network date/time and/or the GPS satellite date/time?

Comment: No, I don't (which is why I didn't fill in an answer below).  I was just suggesting an alternative, in the event nobody suggested a proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

GPS or Network timestamp can be retrieved by using the [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) in the Android Location API.

See the open-source GPSTest project for a fully working example:
https://github.com/barbeau/gpstest

You can request to listen to either Network location updates:

`lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);`

or GPS location updates:

`lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);`

Then, when a location is passed into the LocationListener.onLocationChanged method, you can read the timestamp from that location:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("Timestamp", "New timestamp: " + location.getTime());
}
```

Another option is to make a request to a Network Time Protocol (NTP) server, which is completely independent of the device and cell network.

See this post for details on implementing an NTP client:

[use of ntp service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677674/use-of-ntp-service)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static final String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";
 public static void printTimes() throws IOException {
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        //long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();   //local device time
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();   //server time

        //Get Current Time
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        Log.e("After get PrintTime..","After get PrintTime..>>"+ts);

    enter code here
        Log.e("getCurrentNetworkTime", "Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + returnTime/*time*/);

    }
```