# How to detect when device date is changed

Tags: android

In my project I have to finish activity after completion of some predefined days.

How can I do that.any help will be appricated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544996/is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-the-user-has-changed-the-clock-time-on-their-devic)

Comment: can't you use broadcast receiver to with AlarmManager to do execute particular event on specific day or time ?