# Get the previous (old) time after changing the time

Tags: android, time, android-broadcast

I can get the time change events with the help of  broadcast events (`ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` and `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED`).

**I need to get the previous time after time change**. For example, the current time is 10:00. I am going to change time to 12:00. After time change, time will be changed to 12:00, but I need to get the previous time (10:00) at the time of time change.

Note: Time can be changed from any other app or from settings.

Comment: Get one static variable and everytime when you change the value of time set  the previous value to static variable and then access it anywhere you want.

Comment: Time won't be change from my app.It can be changed by any other application. Then how can I maintain the previous time (Before change time)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the solution I found can help you:

([Is there a way to detect when the user has changed the clock time on their device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544996/is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-the-user-has-changed-the-clock-time-on-their-devic))

The above solution could work setting a static variable on BOOT of device with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, and sum with `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. With this sum you have the before time.

But there is a problem (I don't know if it matters to you), if the user does not reboot the device, then your diff will be `== 0` and you will not be able to have this diff between old and actual `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: It works, nice idea. One thing I add is to adjust the "starting time" (i.e. the one you stored on boot) by calculating the difference between old time and new time and add to it after every time change, so you will have the updated & correct time reference when you use this method again.

Comment: It's a nice solution. But I have problem that TIME_SET sometimes receives before BOOT_COMPLETE. It would be nice to have some system id for particular boot session in android, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of change timing task just store current or old time millisecond  in `sharedpreferences` i.e u can use any time even app will not in stack it self

Comment: Time won't be change from my app. It can be change from any other app or from settings. How can I get the previous time..

Comment: whenever u got this receive event then just take current time millisecond then store it i think that the the last time before change

Comment: When I get the current time that will give the time after changed time  only. It won't give the previous time (Before change time)

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android

Comment: then i don't know dude may be u have to some R&D on this if u will get then please let me know also.:)

Comment: Is there any event getting when we just try to change time date setting like before save button press then may be your work will easy

Comment: Sure dude.. Once I get solution I will update you... and Thanks for your kindness..