# How to get my device date

Tags: android

I want to get my android device date and **check** with current date and **compare** number of days left. Tab or device **doesn't have SIM** also. 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you exactly want? Do you want to calculate the difference between current date and the day when next SIM will be inserted? Or with the day when it will be turned on?

Comment: see this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/17175444

Answer (score 5):

Android API for managing times `android.text.format.Time`

For getting current time:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
```

To calculate differences between two time, you can try this code

```
Time time1;
Time time2;
long diff = time1.toMillis(false) - time2.toMillis(false);
// Now 'diff' contains difference between those two time in milliseconds
```

**Update #1**

> This class was deprecated in API level 22.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code to get the device date.

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String dateFormat = s.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your posts. When others edit your posts for you to improve the formatting in a non-destructive way, the least you can do is to appreciate their help. If you don't like the idea of anyone else editing your posts for any reason, then this site may not be for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Calling `new Date()` is the same as `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())`