# Android: Callback when 'Use network-provided time' is enabled

Tags: android, settings

In my application, I would like to know if there is a callback method when "Use network-provided time" is enabled in the device.

I could check whether it is enabled or not by the following:

```
Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```

But I dont have idea about a callback method when it is enabled. And I couldn't find it in google.

[image]

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17175444/905349) help?

Comment: I have tried that already, but it gets triggered even if the user manually changes the time, when "Use network-provided time" is enabled and in all possible cases - when network time is different from device time or time is changed manually.

Answer (score 0):

In your oncreate,

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Settings.Global.getUriFor(AUTO_TIME),true,autoTimeObserver)
```

Then clean up,

```
contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(autoTimeObserver)
```