# Moving imageview from position A to B with specific time?

Tags: android, timer, imageview, handler

Hey guys right now I'm not developing an app but just for learning purpose I wanted to ask that can we move the `imagview` from position A to B in a given time? If the time is **07:00am** in the phone then the `imageview` should start moving and reach position B when the time is **10:00am** for example. I think it is possible. But how can we achieve this? By using `handler` or `timer`?

Answer (score 1):

How about use view animation and set duration in 3hour?

Comment: Will it work same way? I was thinking about it too...Can you show me an example? Like playing the animation for 3 hours and after that set `imageview` visibility to invisible?

Comment: there's many example in stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation  the problem is application state, if app going to background or terminate..

Comment: And the hardest point is I think to run it with system time. Asked this question twice but I'm not getting the accurate answer, please help me guys!

Comment: your should know system time by broadcast , android broadcast time change. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544996/is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-the-user-has-changed-the-clock-time-on-their-devic you also implement broadcast receiver and receive broadcast each minute  then change view position.

Comment: Oh I hope now this will be possible by using `BroadcastReceiver`! By combining all knowledge at this post can you show me an example project? I'm a little newbie to this! I WOULD BE VERY THANKFUL! Please can you show sample project?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `AlarmManager` to do this:

Sample code example: (Do some action: just like start an activity in specify time, or you can use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` to create a `Broadcast` and send)

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// The Activity you want to start
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
// Create pendingIntent
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
        .getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
// Set a alarm in specify time
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
```

For more information, visit the official website: [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Oh i think it should work. Can you show me example as I described in question? It'll help me alot! I'll accept your answer!

Comment: If you want the imageview move with the passage of time, you need to use this method: alarmManager.setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation).

Comment: But where to set the passage of time?