# How to get current time for different time server in java?

Tags: java, android

i have three time server,time-nw.nist.gov, time1.ucla.edu ,time.ien.it
now how can i get current time for all this server in java/android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of ntp service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677674/use-of-ntp-service)

Answer (score 1):

Check Apache Commons Net library

https://commons.apache.org/net/

From their [example](https://commons.apache.org/net/examples/ntp/TimeClient.java):

```
public static final void timeTCP(String host) throws IOException
{
    TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
    try {
          // We want to timeout if a response takes longer than 60 seconds
          client.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
          client.connect(host);
          System.out.println(client.getDate());
    } finally {
          client.disconnect();
    }
}
```