# Measure long time intervals

Tags: java, android

Checking the method `System.currentTimeMilllis()` it says:

```
This method shouldn't be used for measuring timeouts or other 
elapsed time measurements, as changing the system time can affect the results.
```

and other method like SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() resets if the system is reset

So if I want to measure time in order to do a certain action once every two days regardless of whether user changes the system time, how can I measure it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Comment: You should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677674/use-of-ntp-service to get the real time from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for `Measure long time intervals` - you can run a timer that updates a second's counter, it will not depend on system time

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like [`AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method to launch your action at regular interval

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private long difference ;

//This should be saved from when 2 days is to be checked
SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        syncdate = myPrefs.getLong("difference", System.currentTimeMillis());

    String olddate = changeFormat(syncdate);
    String newdate = changeFormat(System.currentTimeMillis());//This is the new date
    difference = getDate(olddate, newdate);


        public static String changeFormat(long date){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

            Date resultdate = new Date(date);
            String format = sdf.format(resultdate);
            return format;
        }

        public static long getDate(String firstdate,String SecondDate)
        {
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            String arr[] =firstdate.split("/");
            String arr1[] = SecondDate.split("/");
            int sty =Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            int stm = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            int std = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
            int sty1 = Integer.parseInt(arr1[0]);
            int stm1 = Integer.parseInt(arr1[1]);
            int std1 = Integer.parseInt(arr1[2]);

            calendar1.set(sty, stm, std);
            calendar2.set(sty1, stm1, std1);
            long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
            long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
            long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            return diffDays;

        }
```